# Create Email object and update body_str afterwards in Perl

Tags: perl, email

I am trying to update a script so that it can send an email using the [`Email::MIME`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::MIME) object.

I create email object, and then later on update the body of the message, as the message body can change depending on different circumstances.

I have the following code

```
my $message = Email::MIME->create(
    header_str => [
        From => 'someone@example.com',
        To  => 'someoneelse@example.com',
        Subject => 'This is the subject'
    ],
    attributes => {
        encoding => 'quoted-printable',
        charset => 'ISO-8859-1'
    }
);

if ( $i > 1 ) {
   $message->body_str = "Here's one message";
}
else {
   $message->body_str = "Here's seconds message";
}
```

When I do the above I get the following error:

> Can't modify non-lvalue subroutine call

The error line is referencing where I am updating `body_str`

Comment: You have a solution to your problem. But I can't help wondering why you don't just defer the creation of the email until after you know all of the details you need.

Comment: I agree. Why do you create a half-finished message and leave it hanging around until it can be completed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$message->body_str` is a get method, not set.

What you are looking for is `body_set` or probably `body_str_set`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Email::MIME;
my $message = Email::MIME->create(
    header_str => [
        From => 'someone@example.com',
        To  => 'someoneelse@example.com',
        Subject => 'This is the subject'
    ],
    attributes => {
        encoding => 'quoted-printable',
        charset => 'ISO-8859-1'
    }
);
#put your conditionals here
print $message->body_set('Blah');
```

Comment: That did the trick, could not find that anywhere on Google. Thanks for the help

Comment: Why were you looking on Google? Why didn't you just read [the module's documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::MIME)? You linked to it in your question, so you know it exists.

Comment: Congratulations on the 10k :)

Comment: @simbabque: Ha! Thanks :D

Comment: @DaveCross Actually I didn't link it in the question - someone edited the question think they added the link

Comment: @Boardy: Ah, yes. I see that now. Well, there's a good lesson for you. Instead of looking on Google, search MetaCPAN for the documentation of the module that you're using.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, you must use `body_set` or `body_str_set` to change the value of the body text

Use

```
$message->body_set("Here's one message")
```

if you want to pass a simple 7-bit ASCII string, or if your string is already encoded to conform with the message's character set. The module will automatically encode it according to the message's character set before storing it

Or use

```
$message->body_str_set("Here's one message")
```

if you want to pass a general unencoded Unicode string. You will need to be careful about any literal strings you use, as the result depends on the encoding your editor adopts when it writes the file

It is generally best to add `use utf8` at the top of your program, and ensure that your editor writes UTF-8 data. That will cause Perl to read your source code and decode it as UTF-8, storing your strings as basic Unicode data that you can pass to `body_str_set`.